# What is the equivalent python code for RSA.SignData in .NET?

Tags: python, .net, rsa, sha1

In a document I saw the below code:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(“<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>oQRshGhLf2Fh...”);

byte[] signMain = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), new
                     SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
sign = Convert.ToBase64String(signMain);
```

It seems that it first signs data with `RSA` and `SHA1`, then base64 encode it. It reads RSA key from an XML.

The code I used to sign data in python is as below:

```
key = open('priv_key.pem', "r").read()
rsakey = RSA.importKey(key)
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsakey)
digest = SHA256.new()
digest.update(data)
sign = signer.sign(digest)
```

First of all I converted `XML` to `PEM` then used the code above to sign data.

The problem is the output of `.NET` conversion is different from the on in `Python`. It does not work the way I wanted. How could I exactly convert the `.NET` code in python? What is here that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python says that you used SHA-2-256 (`SHA256.new()`) and in .NET you used SHA-1(-160) (`new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()`).  One presumes it would be equivalent if you used the same algorithm on both sides.

Comment: I've used SHA1, but the output was different.